# MS Project data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, business-objects, ms-project

I have been given the task to Load all our company's project data from MS Project into SQL Server to be able to create reports and dashboards from the project data.

I know you can export a specific projects data into a access database, but every project must have it's own access database. So my first thoughts was to create some kind of dynamic access SSIS connector and ETL. So that the project managers export their projects to access and the SSIS package takes care of the rest.

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

My company also have a SharePoint infrastructure as well as SAP BusinessObjects infrastructure. Is there a way I can accomplish this by the use of SharePoint or bobj

Answer (score 3):

The simplest but costy way is called MS Project Server - it stores all data in MS SQL database already, has precalculated reporting database and so on. Here is a link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh973404.aspx. The last version can be either installed locally or hosted by Microsoft.

Another option I see is to use kind of automation around MS Project which will load project plan, extract all interested information and upload to to your database. There is no big magic in this solution.

The third option is to export projects to XML and then use the XML to upload data to SQL Server database. This solution is also doable through Project automation

Comment: It may cost, but compare that to the man-hours building and maintaining your own. To me, if you know you want the features, this purchase is a no-brainer.

Answer (score 1):

After defining your database and column structure in SQL Server, just use Project VBA to A) collect the project and task data into an array, B) set a connection string to your database, then C) send it. I have created several applications around this procedure and it works very well.